# literal newline/carriage found in data exported with pandas to csv

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, csv, pandas, newline

I have the following text file that has CRLF at the end of each line and that has a relatively small number of bad rows (b'Skipping line 55000: expected 14 fields, saw 15\n').

```
0.0;0.7;John;0.29
1.0;0.23;Mike;0.55
0.0;0.72;;Jane;;-3.4
0.0;0.98;Gil;0.68
0.0;0.48;;;0
1.0;0.34;Karl;0.73
0.0;0.44;James;0.06
1.0;0.4;Kiki;0.74
0.0;0.18;Albert;0.18
1.0;0.53;Mark;0.53
```

I import the file with pandas, python 3.5.2 for windows 10 as follows:

```
with open('E:\DATA\my_file.txt','rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', encoding='CP1252', error_bad_lines=False) // skipping bad rows
```

df looks like this: // the bad rows seem to be empty now

```
0.0;0.7;John;0.29
1.0;0.23;Mike;0.55

0.0;0.98;Gil;0.68

1.0;0.34;Karl;0.73
0.0;0.44;James;0.06
1.0;0.4;Kiki;0.74
0.0;0.18;Albert;0.18
1.0;0.53;Mark;0.53
```

Then I export the table into csv as follows:

```
with open('E:\DATA\csv_file.csv','w',newline='\n') as outfile:
    df.to_csv(outfile, sep=';',index = False, line_terminator = '\r')
```

csv_file.csv looks like this: // the empty rows seem to be removed

```
0.0;0.7;John;0.29
1.0;0.23;Mike;0.55
0.0;0.98;Gil;0.68
1.0;0.34;Karl;0.73
0.0;0.44;James;0.06
1.0;0.4;Kiki;0.74
0.0;0.18;Albert;0.18
1.0;0.53;Mark;0.53
```

Unfortunately when I import the file into postgres with the following code:

```
set client_encoding to 'WIN1252';
COPY my_table FROM 'E:\DATA\csv_file.csv' (DELIMITER(';'));
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  literal newline found in data
HINT:  Use "\n" to represent newline.
CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, line 25408: ""
```

When I open the csv_file in nopetad++, I see that it has "CR" at the end of each row up to line 25407, line 25408 and a few others have "CRLF" at the end of the line.
I tried a few things I read on this site like opnening the file in binary mode, but nothing helped.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here and how I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `df = pd.read_csv(r''E:\DATA\my_file.txt'', sep=';', encoding='CP1252', error_bad_lines=False)`?

Comment: It gives me a "invalid syntax". The " r' " seems to be an issue

Comment: Sorry, it should be: `df = pd.read_csv(r'E:\DATA\my_file.txt', sep=';', encoding='CP1252', error_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: it's difficult to reproduce this error... Can you upload somewhere a __reproducible__ CSV file and post here a link to it?

Comment: When I copy-paste a part of the file, all CR become CRLF. The error message in postgres remains the same.

Comment: Please try: `pd.read_csv(r'E:\DATA\my_file.txt', sep=';', encoding='CP1252', error_bad_lines=False).to_csv(r'E:\DATA\csv_file.csv', sep=';', index = False)` and then try to read it in PostgreSQL...

Comment: Unfortunately now line 25408 ends "CR" and line 25409 starts with "CRLF". This happens also for the few other lines that ended with "CRLF".

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE2:** it just works fine:

```
In [194]: pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\onetest.txt', sep=';')
Out[194]:
   COL1  COL2    COL2.1        COL3  COL4  COL5      COL6    COL7 COL8  COL9  COL10
0    23  21.0        UP  15/08/1986  BOBO   NaN   1071001   268-Z  DON  1620    NaN
1  012R  65.0        UP  15/10/1986  ESTO   NaN  15065108   066-B  DON  8415    NaN
2   234   8.0  EIJFTERF  17/12/1989  KING   NaN  15571508  0776-V   UP  6329    NaN
```

**UPDATE:** if your file(s) are small enough to fit into memory you can try this:

```
import io
data = []
with open(r'E:\DATA\my_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.rstrip())
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=';', encoding='CP1252', error_bad_lines=False)
df.to_csv(r'E:\DATA\csv_file.csv', sep=';', index = False)
```

**OLD answer:**

You are using `'\r'` as a line-break and PostgreSQL's COPY command expects `'\n'`, so try the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'E:\DATA\my_file.txt', sep=';', encoding='CP1252', error_bad_lines=False)
df.to_csv(r'E:\DATA\csv_file.csv', sep=';', index = False)
```

in PostgreSQL:

```
set client_encoding to 'WIN1252';
COPY my_table FROM 'E:\DATA\csv_file.csv' (DELIMITER(';'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately now line 25408 ends "CR" and line 25409 starts with "CRLF". This happens also for the few other lines that ended with "CRLF".

Comment: The postgres error is now: ERROR:  literal carriage return found in data
HINT:  Use "\r" to represent carriage return.

Comment: My issue seems to be solved as follow: I tried opening E:\DATA\csv_file.csv with notepad++, copying its content to a new text file in notepad++ I named txt_file.txt. txt_file.txt is generates no errors in postgresql; however since I have hundreds of files to read, this manual process is far from efficient.

Comment: I tried np.savetxt('E:\DATA\a_textfile.txt',df.values,delimiter = ';',fmt='%6.2f'), but this gives a mismatch error and np.savetxt('E:\DATA\a_textfile.txt',df.values,delimiter = ';',fmt='%.s') returns an empty file.

Comment: @JamieLee, it's hard to help you not being able to reproduce your error - can you upload somewhere a __reproducible__ sample?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, my problem is solved by copy-pasting the content of the output file in a new text file. I am afraid the owner of the file won't let me share the original file. I have now trouble figuring out how to directly exporting the output file to a new text file.

Comment: Hi @MaxU, I hope you are still interested in the problem I had the other day. If you still are, I think I managed to create a reproductible sample that you can find below:
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/4asjahr9jfonoup/onetest.txt?dl=0)

Comment: @JamieLee, it's still working just fine for me (Python 3.5.2, Pandas 0.19.1, Windows 64bit)...

Comment: Can you see the CR in line 4 and the CRLF in line 5? Also the CR in line 6 and the CRLF in line 7?

Comment: This is annoying: I get "ERROR:  missing data for column "col2" when copying this file in postgres. Reproducing the erroe seems harder than I thought

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that onetest.tx is the output from pandas that I am trying to load into postgresql